# Web browsers into kiosk mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have currently found a way to place the currently installation of Internet Explorer into kiosk mode using asp.net and VB

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "-k " & "http://www.google.co.uk")
```

the "-k" parameter is the command that puts the browser into kiosk mode, however, other browsers such as chrome will only put the new instance of the page into another tab and firefox just opens the browser without loading the window. 
I need to know what commands to pass so that chrome and firefox will respond in the same way as IE.

Many thanks

Comment: Googling `browsername kiosk mode` will work - apparently, Chrome doesn't have Kiosk mode at the moment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=12bde481a208c4ca&hl=en

Comment: FF can do it only using a plugin: [Firefox 3.6 Kiosk mode](http://superuser.com/q/120294)

Comment: Thank you for the plugin advice. I need to use an open source browser as the software will be run on a linutop box.

Comment: There are two plugins for Firefox, however, they only work with versions up to 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome browser can do KIOSK mode with this command.

```
chrome.exe --chrome-frame -kiosk "your web page".
```

The good thing with Chrome is that you can build apps that can use the webkit animation and they look great for a KIOSK type applications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be interested in Windows Steady State, it's discontinued and doesn't run on win 7, but if you have XP or vista, it will let you lock down the PC nice and tight. This way you can restrict the use of programs to browsers you want (if you can't lock down chrome and ff) and on a reboot, it will clear any changes to the PC, basically returning you to a clean state status

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState

Comment: Thanks for the post, it has been decided that the software will now run on a linutop box which has a kiosk mode built into it that will do what I need to.